# Not Much Voting Going On

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, votes

While I was browsing around the site, there appears to be a lack of voting going on in the site. Personally, whenever I go to a StackExchange website, I usually vote up the good questions and comments that are asked/answered.

Is there any incentive for users to vote here in Writers-StackExchange or is this different from SuperUser/OnStartup?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much traffic since the initial announcement.  I'm voting things up too, but there's only so much voting a handful of people can do.

Comment: Well, we've got until Thursday, and then the question of whether enough voting is happening will become moot.  And once we go into public beta, we go social crazy and invite the world!!!  That should shake things up a bit? :)

Comment: Don't get discouraged!  I already have a bunch of people from the NaNoWriMo community planning to head over in the public beta, and I bet I'm not the only one who's spread the word since private beta started.  It's also worth noting that during the final crunch of NaNoWriMo was probably not the best time to launch the writers.se beta -- too many people in the writing community are heads-down on their NaNoNovels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect this is partly a matter of getting more people here. The population of users in a  private beta will be naturally small.